# How to demonstrate sin(π/6) = 1/2?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to demonstrate:

$$ \sin(π/6) =  \sin(30º) = 1/2 $$

Which property or assumption I should use to start?

Comment: Use a equilateral triangle.

Comment: it depends how you have defined the sine function

Comment: I'll check, thank you. @Ana

Answer (score 4):

Hint for other solution:
$$1 = \sin(\pi/2) = \sin(3(\pi/6)) = \text{some polynomial}(\sin(\pi/6)).$$
(for the last $=$ apply [some trigonometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities))

Answer (score 3):

If you consider an equilateral triangle ABC whose each side is "a",each angle will be 60 degrees,draw perpendicular from point A on side BC as AD, angle DAB=angle DAC=30 degrees.on calculating geometrically you will get BD=a/2,also AB=a.
sinBAD = sin(π/6) = BD/AB =(a/2)/a = 1/2.

Comment: What is mathjex

Comment: Is it similar to latex?

Comment: @SathasivamK Yes, and it's called MathJ**a**x.

Comment: OK ...alright..